# For an elliptic curve defined over a field $K$, how to perform operations to calculate the coordinates if the points lies in another field $K'$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, elliptic-curves, cryptography

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined by the equation $E:y^2=x^3+ax+b$ over the field $K$ i.e. $a$, $b$ are elements of $K$. Let’s have another field $K’$ and let’s take a couple $(x,y)$ element of $E(K′)$, how to calculate say “$ax$” while $a$ is an element of $K$ and $x$ is an element of another field $K′$. I know it's possible if $K'$ is a field extension of $K$. But how to perform the operation? Is $a$ taken as an element of $K'$ or as a coefficient in $K$?

Comment: Why do you need to talk about $ax$ for different fields? Indeed, for, say, $a\in \mathbb{F}_p$ and $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ this does not make sense. The curve is defined over a field $K$, so $a,b\in K$ and we are looking for points on the curve, i.e., with $x,y\in K$.

Comment: I thought it is defined for certain cases, for example if $a∈F_p$ and $x∈F_{p^k}$.

Comment: Yes, but still you would consider the curve then over one field (the bigger one here).

Comment: So, if we have $a=1+t$ and $x=1+t$ elements of $F_4$ and $F_8$ respectively ($F_8$ is an extension of $F_4$). We take $a$ as an element of $F_8$, and we don't even have to compute $ax$ modulo an irreductible polynomial of degre $2$ (say $1+x^2$)?

Comment: I don't really see why we have to do the reduction modulo $1+x^2$. If we don't do it, $ax$ is still an element of $F_8$.

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_8$ is not an extension of $\Bbb{F}_4$. But $\Bbb{F}_4$ and $\Bbb{F}_8$ are both subfields of $\Bbb{F}_{64}$, so you can do the calculations in there. But, I suspect your understanding of finite fields is a bit shaky. For example, it is impossible that $\Bbb{F}_4$ and $\Bbb{F}_8$ would share an element $t$ other than $0,1$. I suspect you are confusing the coset of $x$ modulo $x^2+x+1$ (could be the $t\in\Bbb{F}_4$ with the coset of $x$ modulo $x^3+x+1$ (which could be the $t\in\Bbb{F}_8$). Those two $t$s have nothing to do with each other.